# Bootstrap menu not changing to mobile menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

For some reason I cannot get the mobile menu to work on this bootstrap theme. This is Bootstap v3. Does anyone know where exactly I would look in the CSS to fix this? I've tried scanning it and cannot find it.

https://southlakellc.com/

This is the site URL. You will see that if you shrink the browser, the pull-out menu doesnt appear until it's too small. The mobile nav is not appearing at all on mobile devices.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have u defined media queries by your own or you are using bootsttrap ready made menu? check for media queries where they have specified min-width and max-width .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your `<head>` :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will fix it!

Hope it helps :)

Comment: That worked! What exactly does this do? I thought that it had something to do with the @media tags in the CSS?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp explains it most simply